# parse xml files and get values of attributes from the tags and perform calculations on them

Tags: python, xml, loops, xml-parsing

I have a folder containing XML files which somewhat look like this:

```
<testsuite file="test_apis.py" name="activities.tests time="8.679">

<testcase classname="testcase_1" file="test_apis.py" line="171" name="test_results" time="1.965">
```

I need to parse the file and get the value of time attribute under test case(second line of the code).

Here are the things I need to do with the files:

1. I want to loop over a list where I have like about 100 files and
   calculate time for each specified classname(there are about 6 unique
   classnames in all the files) and access "time" attribue of the tag and then sum up all the instances where the same classname occurs. Each classname occurs in one file only once but there are multiple instances of the same classname in one file.
2. Distribute the classname in groups so that the time consumed by all testcases will be the same.
3. Create a csv file with the testcase name and the total time consumed.

I have created a fun to iterate over the files and store them into a list:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

# Empty list to store path of xml files

path_list = []

# Function to iterate folder and store path of xml files.
# Can be modified to take the path as an argument via command line if required
time_sum = []
testcase = []


def calc_time(path):
    for path in glob.iglob(f'{path}/*.xml'):
        path_list.append(path)

    try:
        for file in path_list:
            xml_df = pd.read_xml(file, xpath=".//testcase")
            # Get the classname values from the XML file
            testcase_v = xml_df.at[0, 'classname']
            testcase.append(testcase_v)
            # Get the aggregate time value of all instances of the classname
            time_sum_test = xml_df['time'].sum()
            time_sum.append(time_sum_test)

            case_time = dict(zip(testcase, time_sum))

    except Exception as ex:
        msg_template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
        message = msg_template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
        print(message)


calc_time('assignment-1/data')
```

Please help me out..

Comment: Consider pandas for calculation and grouping needs which now support reading shallow XML with [read_xml](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html). However, your posted markup is _not_ XML which by definition is well-formed with a root and closing tags among other rules. If post is partial view, please post fuller example and not line snippets.

Comment: I can't post the full snippet of the code its confidential. how can I parse the xml file and read vlaues of the tags with the pandas method you told about? I can't actually understand the process in the docs

Comment: It depends on how XML is structured. But simply build a data frame from the method: `xml_df = pd.read_xml("input.xml", xpath=".//testsuite")`. This will migrate all attributes of `<testsuite>` as columns with values in rows. Redact or use a mock XML that retains similar structure as original.

Comment: I figured out and I have a dictionary containg all the "classnames" of the <testcase>  and their aggregate "time". Now I need to distribute `classname` by their time into 5 groups, so that, total `time` for each group will approximately same.

Comment: "Please help me out" - What exactly do you need help with? Please ask about one reproducible problem at a time.

Comment: @mzjn I need to distribute classname by their time into 5 groups, so that, total time for each group will approximately same.

Comment: That is item 2 in the question. You had two other items, Ask about one item at a time and please explain **what the problem is**. Don't just say "I need this".

Comment: I have updated the code later when I completed the No.1 item. I can;t figure out the groupby clause in pandas to group these classnames into 5 groups such that the total time consumed by all the groups will look approximately equal